# A special character turns into symbol when form is submitted

Tags: java, jsp, special-characters

I have a page with a form where user have to fill inputs, their login are filled automatically in hidden input, and I have a user with a login with a special character (in my case the character is `é`). And when the form is submitted the special character turns into the symbol `Ã©`. Here is what I have :

**FORM**

```
<input type="hidden" name="Employe" value="<%= employe %>">
```

when I inspect the element I can see that the value is `rémax`

And when I do this

```
String employe = request.getParameter("Employe");
System.out.println(employe);
```

The output is `rÃ©max`

This not seems to be an issue with charset because I can display special characters in both views. Why the special character  is not displayed as expected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` to the very start of the page.

If that doesn't work you might try the following:

1. It's a `GET` request and the server isn't configured to use UTF-8 to parse request URI. If you are using Tomcat then set `URIEncoding` attribute of the HTTP Connector in `/conf/server.xml` to `UTF-8`.
2. If it's a `POST` request, then you need to ensure that the servletcontainer uses `UTF-8` to encode the request body. You can do that by `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` beforehand.

Comment: None of these solutions worked and it's a `GET`request

Comment: Maybe your browser is unable to auto-detect `UTF-8` encoding which java defaults to. Try to force character encoding to `ISO-8859-1` using `request.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1")`